# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ClassPenangkap'.can anyone help me?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety, null-safety

```dart
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'crud.dart';
    import 'class_penangkap.dart';
    import 'acces_database.dart';
    import 'enter.dart';
    
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      HomeState createState() => HomeState();
    }
    
    class HomeState extends State<Home>{
        CRUD dbHelper = CRUD();
      late Future<List<ClassPenangkap>> future;
     
      
     
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        updateListView();
      }
    void updateListView() {
        setState(() {
          future = dbHelper.getContactList();
        });
      }
    
      Future<ClassPenangkap> navigateToEntryForm(
          BuildContext context, ClassPenangkap contact) async {
            var result = await
             Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return EntryForm(contact);
        }));
        return result;
      }
    
      
      
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Daftar Data-Data'),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder<List<ClassPenangkap>>(
            future: future,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              Card cardo(ClassPenangkap contact) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              child: Icon(Icons.people),
            ),
            title: Text(
              contact.name.toString()
            ),
            subtitle: Text(contact.phone.toString()),
            trailing: GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () async {
                int result = await dbHelper.delete(contact);
                if (result > 0) {
                  updateListView();
                }
              },
            ),
            onTap: () async {
              var contact2 = await navigateToEntryForm(context, contact);
              if (contact2 != null) {
                int result = await dbHelper.update(contact2);
                if (result > 0) {
                  updateListView();
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                    children: snapshot.data!.map((todo) => cardo(todo)).toList());
              } else {
                return SizedBox();
              }
            },
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            tooltip: 'Tambah Data',
            onPressed: () async {
             //**SYNTAX ERROR from the below code**
              var contact = await navigateToEntryForm(context, null);
              if (contact != null) {
                int result = await dbHelper.insert(contact);
                if (result > 0) {
                  updateListView();
                }
              }
            },
          ),
          
        );
      }
    }
```

***This is just to past the review question***

JUST IGNORE THIS

ERROR DETAILS

error: The argument type '() → Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(Null) → FutureOr'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [fluttercam] lib\packs\reg.certificate.dart:38)

When I use '_' (underscore / Private variable) the code is working fine, Error resolved!

controller.initialize().then((_) {});
Can anyone explain what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: What's with the "this is just to past the review questio JUST IGNORE THIS" ???

Answer (score 0):

You defined the function as

```
Future<ClassPenangkap> navigateToEntryForm(
      BuildContext context, ClassPenangkap contact)
```

which means none of the parameters can be null, so `navigateToEntryForm(context, null)` is not possible. If you want your function to allow null values you need to indicate it with a `?`, like

```
Future<ClassPenangkap> navigateToEntryForm(
      BuildContext context, ClassPenangkap? contact)
```

You might run into a new error though on `EntryForm(contact)` if that one also doesn't accept null values.